# How to write correctly a regular expression

Tags: python

I am trying to focus for data from a specific file based on regular expression. This is an example of data:

```
Timestamp 1547908293  ID=02141592cc0000000500000000000000 Dest_ID=02141592cc00000005ffffffb00abeff activity_ti9_end of receiving ACK frame event
```

The result of my regular expression may look like this:

```
('1547908293','02141592cc0000000500000000000000','02141592cc00000005ffffffb00abeff','activity_ti9' )
```

This is my resolution but it does not work:

`r'\bTimestamp\s+([0-9]+)\s+ID=(\w{16})\s+Dest_ID=(\w{16})\s+activity_ti9'`

Comment: You should consider using `.split()` instead of regular expressions. They are quite expensive to evaluate and hard to maintain.

Comment: Why do you only set the second/third pattern to look for 16 word characters when it  should be 32?

Comment: @KlausD. I have a big log file it is more easier to use regular expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
r'\bTimestamp\s+([0-9]+)\s+ID=(\w{18})\s+Dest_ID=(\w{18})\s+(\w{12})'
```